# Passing Personally Identifiable Information in Google Products

Tags: encryption, get, adsense

I am new developer and built a site with some google ads ([www.freemics.com](http://www.freemicsnyc.com))

The other day I got an email from Google with the following message:

*"It has come to our attention that you are passing personally identifiable information (PII) to Google through your use of one or more of Google's advertising products -- DFP, AdSense, and/or DoubleClick AdExchange."*

I believe this has something to do with my using GET to pass some data in the URL without encrypting it. But I dont know what this has to do with the ads. I never altered any of that code.

Can anyone give me more information about this. Would using encryption when passing data in GET resolve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When an Adsense ad unit runs on your site, an ad request is sent to Google.  This ad request includes a Request URL header which contains the URL of the page serving the ad. As such, if the URL contains unencrypted PII, that data is passed on to google.  Google has some [best practices](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6156630?hl=en&ref_topic=6162392) for complying with the policy.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use form tags with method="GET". You should always use POST forms so the form data won't be transfered through query strings (e.g. *http://foo.bar/?name=foo&lastname=bar*). When you use POST forms, the issue should be fixed.